# How to stop print echo result in output without function executed

Tags: php

It might be a silly question but,

I created a single PHP to do some checks in my site and at the final result
I used `echo` to print it or print "nothing found" in case function failed

but the issue is, the PHP file keep printing the "nothing found" even if i didn't click the "submit" button

```
if (function failed) {
    echo "not found";
} else {
    echo "do stuff here";
}
```

the php file keep printing "not found"
I tried `ob_clean() ob_end_flush() ob_end_clean()` but it didn't work

**Full code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Check IMDB</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Check IMDB&nbsp;&nbsp;">
            <div>
                <textarea style="width: 50%; margin-top:7px; height: 150px;" id="urlbox" name="urlbox" placeholder="Add imdb links here (one per line)"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

<?php
$imdblink = "";
$imdblink = $_POST['urlbox'];
?>

<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;

echo "<br>";
if (!preg_match_all('~tt\d{7,8}~', $imdblink, $ttids)) {
    echo "no ttids found";
} else {
    $resultSet = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'imdb' AND meta_value IN ('" . implode("','", $ttids[0]) . "');");
    $foundInDatabase = array_column($resultSet, "meta_value");

    foreach ($ttids[0] as $index => $ttid) {
        if (in_array($ttid, $foundInDatabase)) {
            $ttid = '<a style="color:blue;" href="https://www.imdb.com/title/'.$ttid.'/">'.$ttid.'</a>';
        }
        echo "<div>" , ($index + 1) , "- {$ttid}</div>\n";
    }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the entire code to check it? Where to you call this condition?

Comment: Done @Valentin Emil Cudelcu

Comment: You can try check request method $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].

Comment: That's what i did, thanks @Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a name attribute to your submit button and check if the button was pressed.

In your case, you are checking the `urlbox` everytime you run the script.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Check IMDB&nbsp;&nbsp;">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //Here add your code
    }
?>
```

No the script will check the `urlbox` only when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot , works perfect. @Valentin Emil Cudelcu